# is it possible to set the Line Chart background-color through css file - Google Charts

Tags: svg, charts, google-visualization

Is there any way to set the Line Chart background-color through css file?

I can use SVG fill option in css file but this obstruct the grid line color.

I have tried this but no luck

cssClassNames : {
                backgroundColor: 'chart-background',
            },

Comment: why not use the provided [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for `backgroundColor` and `chartArea.backgroundColor`?

Comment: Because it doesn't fit with our requirements as end user can select different themes.

Comment: it's possible to change the option color and redraw the chart based on user selection...